# ReferenceError: login is not defined at submitHandler

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to make a login functionality here. I am using react as a front end and django rest framework as a backend. But this code is saying login is not defined. Though I make a userActions where I defined login. Please help me out, someone.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {Link, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

function LoginPage({ history}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const location = useLocation()
    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'
    
    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const {error, loading, userInfo} = userLogin

    useEffect(() => {
        if(userInfo){
            history.push(redirect)
        }
    },[history, userInfo, redirect])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(login(email, password))
    }
    
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>SIGN IN</h2>
    
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='username'>Username:</label>
                <input 
                    type='email'
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='password'>Password:</label>
                <input 
                    type='password'
                    value={password}
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <button className='signin' type='submit'>Sign In</button>
            <p>Are you new to this Website?</p>
            <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : '/register'}>Sign Up</Link>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage
```

Here is my userActions file below:

```
import axios from 'axios'

import {
    USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOGIN_FAIL,

    USER_LOGOUT,

} from '../constants/userConstants'

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try{
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
        })

        const config = {
            headers:{
                'Content-type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const {data} = await axios.post(
            '/api/users/login/', 
            {'username' : email, 'password': password},
            config
        )

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

        localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch ({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message
        })
    }
}
```

userReducers below:

```
import {
    USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    USER_LOGIN_FAIL,

    USER_LOGOUT,

} from '../constants/userConstants'


const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ?
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null

const initialState = {
    userLogin : {userInfo: userInfoFromStorage}
  }

export const userLoginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
 
        case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload }

        case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

        case USER_LOGOUT:
            return {}

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { postListReducer, postDetailsReducer } from './reducers/postReducers'
import { userLoginReducer } from './reducers/userReducers'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    postList : postListReducer,
    postDetails : postDetailsReducer,
    userLogin : userLoginReducer,
  },
})

export default store
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to import the action from your redux actions on the LoginPage component. where it should be imported at the top level

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {Link, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
import {login}  from "../your file directory for login action"  // here import it.

function LoginPage({ history}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const location = useLocation()
    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'
    
    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const {error, loading, userInfo} = userLogin

    useEffect(() => {
        if(userInfo){
            history.push(redirect)
        }
    },[history, userInfo, redirect])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(login(email, password))
    }
    
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>SIGN IN</h2>
    
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='username'>Username:</label>
                <input 
                    type='email'
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='password'>Password:</label>
                <input 
                    type='password'
                    value={password}
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <button className='signin' type='submit'>Sign In</button>
            <p>Are you new to this Website?</p>
            <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : '/register'}>Sign Up</Link>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: wow, that helped, thanks, but now the new error occured: POST localhost:3000/api/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please check the email and password? with your database? 
401 status tells that authentication failed. this may be 99% due to the wrong email and password.

Answer (score 1):

From what i'm seeing here you are not importing the **login** method!

```
import { login } from '../path-to-action/userActions';
```

Comment: wow, that helped man, but now the new error occured:
POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login/ 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Unauthorized you get when the credentials you send isn't correct like email or/and password